# 2 MySQL db Tables : Have unique IDs (primary key , auto-increment) - Taking both in Consideration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I'm having a small problem with my website , i am designing a website for my school project and had to use a framework for the first time .

I create 2 tables : Student , Professor but i'm having a small issue . When i login to student & then in the link i change the url to the member page of the professor - the professor account shows up without having to login .

I figured out the problem was with the way i implemented it with laravel & found a quick fix.

That happens only if the primary id of the tables are the same in the databases.

The project is due next week , so i want to use a quick fix like :

Is it possible to have different ids in both tables .

Say a user registers a student account , he gets id 1 in that table

another user register a professor account , instead of starting at 1 - it has primary id 2 instead.

then another user register a student account - he gets id 3 ...and so on

Is there any way to implement that ?

Or even  start the id increment at say 2000.

Student/Professor table :

[st http://1.ii.gl/Wyf5KC.png](http://1.ii.gl/Wyf5KC.png)

Comment: Set Student autoincrement from 1 in steps of 2; and Professor autoincrement from 2 in steps of 2.... though `SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;` would affect every autoincrement column in your database

Comment: tbh i would have one table with an account type fields 1 = student, 2=professor for example

Comment: when there are more accounts , they will conflict - like if i add another student , he gets id 2 - then it will conflict with the professor starting at id 2.

Comment: @Jimmy the next generated id would be 3

Comment: how can i set it to increment by 2 in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I already said: `SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;`